# what is the difference between these C statements?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

```
int y = 17*x;
int y = x + 16*x;
int y = x + (x<<4)
```

All are numerically equal to 17x , but is there is any difference between them in terms of execution or anything else ?

Comment: Why don't you profile them and find out ?

Comment: oh and for the last one you actually want `x + (x<<4)`

Comment: How is `x` declared? What value does it hold?

Comment: Disassemble the code and compare. The two last are probably going to be the same as most compilers are pretty good at folding constant expressions.

Comment: AFAIK, bitwise operations are always fast than others.

Comment: @Abhineet - Bitwise operations are only faster in *very* rare cases, or using old hardware with very stupid compilers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
1) int y = 17*x;
2) int y = x + 16*x;
3) int y = x + (x<<4);
```

The difference is this: 1) is readable, 2) is obscure and 3) is even more obscure.

Manual optimizations, replacing multiplication with bitwise-instructions, should not be needed on a modern compiler. It will most likely translate all 3 alternatives to the same machine code.

In case the compiler is bad and it does *not* translate them to the same machine code, then we can't know which is the fastest, since it relies on how fast the underlying assembler instructions are for the specific CPU architecture. Traditionally, logical shift instructions are faster than multiplication instructions, but you can't assume that this is true for all CPUs.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Ah yeah, fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Strictly speaking, it depends on the type and value of `x`. Overflowing a signed `int` is undefined behavior as far as the standard is concerned, so for example an implementation is *allowed* to behave differently according to whether your code contains 2 operations that overflow, or only 1.

Assuming that everything is integers that remain within bounds, the statements have the same meaning. It's plausible that they'll all result in exactly the same emitted code, but you'd have to check that by compiler and compiler options. This is more likely the more optimization you have.

It's also plausible that you'd see one version of the code emitted for the first one (the compiler emits a multiply), and different code emitted for the other two (compiler emits an add and either a multiply by 16 or a shift by 4). Even without optimization, the compiler will evaluate `1<<4` at compile time -- the standard requires that the compiler is able to evaluate such expressions in some contexts, so there's no reason for a compiler not to.